# RoboVM + admob black banner rectangle

Tags: libgdx, admob, robovm

i have followed the libGDX guide here:https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx for my android project everything works great, but on my ios project my banners are showing as black rectangles. I know that my internet is working normally because my interstitial ads load up just fine. I have also made sure that i am using the right admob app key.

Does anyone know why i am seeing black banners?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting a background color on the AdView should make it work:

```
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Check out [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/avwVXvBt_sM) if you still encounter problems